# Conditional show / hide of fields in AEM 6 dialogs

Tags: aem

I am building a relatively straight-forward AEM component with a simple authoring dialog. At the top of my dialog is a select field.  I want certain fields in my dialog to disappear when this select field is set to a specific item.

I have studied the implementation of the Foundation Carousel component, which uses the `cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide-target` attribute, which is fine, but isn't quite the logic I am looking for.  The logic used there is:

**show this field if the select is equal to X**

Whereas I am trying to implement:

**hide this field if the select is equal to X, Y or Z, otherwise show it**

Has anyone else had trouble implementing this kind of logic in their dialogs?

Thank you in advance!

Dave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For TouchUI dialogs there is actually no plugin registry that was heavily used in ExtJS framework. This time, we can actually do all the magic with the use of just clientlibs and jQuery.

Take a look at the base implementation that you are refering to that can be found here: `/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/dropdownshowhide/clientlibs/dropdownshowhide.js`

This is a clientlibs that is attached to `cq.authoring.dialog` category and requires `granite.jquery` to be initialized before. See [clientlibs documentation](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/clientlibs.html) to learn more about it. The script itself is a anonymous function that is invoked with a document parameter and jQuery from granite (see last line in the script: `})(document,Granite.$);`)

If given functionality is not sufficent for you, you can create your own clientlib with a similar simple javascript function that will handle more sophisticated conditions. Please also note, that any attribute placed in the "widget" node will be placed as data attribute in resulting html.

For the node (e.g. `/libs/foundation/components/carousel/cq:dialog/content/items/list/items/column/items/orderBy`) that you want to hide when some condition occurs place property: hideWhen=children,search (don't make it an array as it won't be properly casted to a string in JS). Point a dropdown selector (`/libs/foundation/components/carousel/cq:dialog/content/items/list/items/column/items/listForm@cq-dialog-dropdown-hidefor-target`) to a proper class that you will on the other hand assign to your hideable field.

```
|-listFrom(select)
| |--@cq-dialog-dropdown-hidefor-target=.orderByClass
|
orderBy(autocomplete)
  |--@hideFor=children,search
  |--@class=orderByClass
```

The javascript method for your case could look something like that:

```
 (function(document, $) {
    "use strict";

    // when dialog gets injected
    $(document).on("foundation-contentloaded", function(e) {
        // if there is already an inital value make sure the according target element becomes visible
        showHide($(".cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide", e.target))  ;
    });

    $(document).on("selected", ".cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide", function(e) {
        showHide($(this));
    });

   function showHide(el){
       var widget =  el.data("select");

       if (widget) {

           // get the selector to find the target elements. its stored as data-.. attribute
           var target = el.data("cqDialogDropdownHideforTarget");

           // get the selected value
           var value = widget.getValue();

           // make sure all unselected target elements are hidden.
           var hideFor = $(target).data('hidefor').split(',');

           $(target).not(".hide").addClass("hide");

           // unhide the target element that contains the selected value as data-showhidetargetvalue attribute
           if (hideFor.indexOf(value) == -1) {
               $(target).removeClass("hide");
           }
       }
   }
```

There are some issues with hiding input labels in such case so it might be good idea to wrap the field into the section (granite/ui/components/foundation/well)

Comment: Thank you Mathew, that sounds like just the ticket!

Comment: Any idea how to solve this issue when you are using a multifield component? In that case when you select a value in the dropdown, it will change the visibility of all the components. 
Changing the values is not an option, but maybe playing with the classes?

Comment: Really unfortunate. This should be configurable as part of the data model not by slapping client side code in front of it and pretending it's a good solution.