# AEM 6.1 - How to implement listeners to show/hide the fields in Touch UI dialog

Tags: aem

Like in AEM 6.1 classic dialog, we used to write the extjs to show/hide the fields in dialog, i need some reference which can help in doing the same in touch ui dialog.

Also, how to implement custom multifield in the touch ui dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AEM Components documentation [0] should offer you most of the answers you're looking for.

[0] - https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/components/components-touch-optimized.html#Handling%20Field%20Events

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similiar which enabled/disabled fieldsin a touchUI dialog based on the value of a checkbox (also in the dialog) I ended up writing my own client libray to manage this you can find my solution here: [Conditionally enable/disable fields in AEM 6.1 (granite.ui) TouchUI dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645244/conditionally-enable-disable-fields-in-aem-6-1-granite-ui-touchui-dialogs)